# Retrieved profile from scratch org contains a permission which is unknown to a sandbox, why?

Tags: salesforcedx, permissions, profile

I've been working with SalesforceDX for a while now, and I've always removed profiles from deployments because of similar issues.

Often you will create a simple scratch org, write your code, and then when you retrieve it will bring everything, including profiles. The problem is that the profile metadata lists the permissions given to the profile, and some of them are not recognized by other organizations.

I keep getting similar messages like this when converting and deploying to a sandbox:

```
Unknown user permission: ContentWorkspaces
```

1. Is there a way to describe what the troublesome permissions do, so I can remove the feature from the scratch org definition file?
2. Is there a table that lists what are the possible permissions a profile can have, and what do they do?

Comment: Are you trying to push into a packaging org or Partner Developer Edition? I've found that those orgs come with a feature set that's very divergent from that of even a barebones, non-customized scratch org, which tends to lead to this kind of error.

Comment: No, I'm using a common Enterprise Edition sandbox. It is part of a consulting project I'm working with. We develop in our scratch orgs, then commit the code to a remote GitLab instance, where the code is converted and deployed to the sandbox for QA.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, no, there's no one file/document you can look at that describes all possible permissions. Further, if such a list existed, it might not be accurate for your org, as permissions are only exposed if a related feature exists (e.g. you won't see ContentWorkspaces in your metadata if you don't have Content enabled). The closest list I know of that is an exhaustive list (which it is not) would be [KB 332385](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000332385&type=1&mode=1).

However, in this case, you just need to not enable CRM Content, and you'll avoid that error. Off the top of my head, I don't know of the permission you'd have to enable for this, but it's apparently in your Scratch Org Configuration File.

Comment: I have to explicitly disable CRM Content in the config file then? 

Comment: @RenatoOliveira Yes. I'm not too familiar with the config file parameters, but you'd want to take that feature out.